# Get value of name attribute in form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value of a name attribute in my html form.
I tried:

```
$('input[name=username]').val();
```

but that doesn't work it.

 

Hope someone can help me.

**edit:**

Sorry I wasn't really clear but I want to get the input value of the form.
When I try:

```
GM_setValue ("username", $('input[name=username]').val() );
```

and check about:config after I fill in the form the value of username is empty

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the value of a input element with a certain name attribute or do you want the value of the name attribute ("username" in this case). Your question says the latter but I think you mean the first

Comment: Please show the HTML of the input. What does "doesn't work" mean? What value do you get?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done will get you the value of the `input` with `name=username`. If you want to get the value "username" (not sure why, but I think it is what you are asking) then you can do this:

```
var nameValue = $('input[name=username]').attr("name");
```

---

Assuminge the following HTML:

```
<input name="username" value="my value" />
```

Your original method will return a result of `"my value"`, my method will return a result of `"username"`. If I have misunderstood your requirements then please let me know what you are trying to do, as what you already have should work fine.

[Here is an example of both in action](http://jsfiddle.net/aHFE9/)

Comment: Darn, you were a second quicker than me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  this to get the name

```
$("#id").attr("name");
```